# How to fix the error "Neither the property nor one of the methods... exist and have public access in class..." with Symfony form

Tags: forms, symfony, runtime-error

I am trying to build a form with Symfony. From the moment I added the submit button by adding this {{form_widget(userform.Subscription)}}, I am facing with this error message :

Neither the property "Subscription" nor one of the methods "Subscription()", "getSubscription()"/"isSubscription()"/"hasSubscription()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView".

If you have an idea of what is happening, thank you very much for your help.

Here is my code :

**register.html.twig**

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Incris-toi !{% endblock %}

{% block main %}

{{form_start(userform)}}

    <div class="form container">

        <div class="formpage">
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                {{form_widget(userform.occupation, {'attr' : {'placeholder' : 'Quelle est ton occupation (ton métier, tes études…) ?', 'class' : 'form-control'}})}}
                {{form_label(userform.occupation, 'Quelle est ton occupation (ton métier, tes études…) ?', {'label_attr' : {'class' : 'label'}})}}
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <p>De quel pays es-tu originaire ?</p>
                {{form_widget(userform.nationality)}}
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <p>Quelle est ta langue maternelle ?</p>
                {{form_widget(userform.nativelanguage)}}
            </div>
            <div class="optional mb-3">
                <p>Quelle langue souhaites-tu pratiquer ?</p>
                {{form_widget(userform.wishedlanguages, {'attr' : {'class' : 'form-control'}})}}
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex">
                <button type="button" class="prev btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary mt-4 d-flex align-items-center me-auto">&lt;<span class="previous">Précédent</span></button>
                {{form_widget(userform.Subscription, {'attr' : {'class' : 'btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary mt-4 d-flex ms-auto'}})}}
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

{{form_end(userform)}}

{% endblock %}
```

**UserType.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\CallbackTransformer;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CountryType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\BirthdayType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\LanguageType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\RepeatedType;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('gender', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => [
                    'Je suis ...' => '',
                    'un homme' => 'male',
                    'une femme' =>'female',
                    'non-binaire' => 'non-binary'
                ]
            ])
            ->add('lastname')
            ->add('firstname')
            ->add('birthdate', BirthdayType::class, [
                'placeholder' => [
                    'year' => 'Année', 'month' => 'Mois', 'day' => 'Jour',
                ],
                'choice_translation_domain' => true
            ])
            ->add('occupation')
            ->add('nationality', CountryType::class, [
                'placeholder' => 'Je choisis un pays',
            ])
            ->add('nativelanguage', LanguageType::class, [
                'placeholder' => 'Je choisis ta langue maternelle',
            ])
            ->add('wishedlanguages', LanguageType::class, [
                'placeholder' => 'Je choisis une langue étrangère',
            ])
            ->add('email')
            ->add('password', PasswordType::class, [
                'mapped' => false
            ])
            ->add('password', RepeatedType::class, [
                'type' => PasswordType::class,
                'invalid_message' => 'Les deux mots de passe doivent être identiques.',
                'options' => ['attr' => ['class' => 'password-field']],
                'required' => true,
                'first_options'  => ['label' => 'Password'],
                'second_options' => ['label' => 'Repeat Password'],
            ])
            ->add('roles', CheckboxType::class, [
                'label' => 'Je m\'inscris uniquement en tant qu\'organisateur.',
                'required' => false,
                'compound' => true,
            ])
            ->get('roles')
            ->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
                function ($arrayAsBool) {
                return in_array("ROLE_ADMIN", $arrayAsBool);
            },
                function ($boolAsArray) {
                return $boolAsArray ? ["ROLE_ADMIN"] : ["ROLE_USER"];
            }))
            ->add('Subscription', SubmitType::class);
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
            'translation_domain' => 'forms'
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `->get('roles')` seems strange.  Almost like it should generate a syntax error.  Just for kicks, comment out the get line as well as the entire addModelTransformer section and see if that impacts the error.

Comment: Yes, my error changed. I have now : Unable to transform value for property path "roles": Expected a Boolean. I opened this ticket when I had this error : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73571096/how-can-i-insert-checkbox-in-a-form-with-symfony/73572054?noredirect=1#comment129939338_73572054

Comment: I see.  For some reason Twig thinks Subscription is just a regular data field.  You already rendered a button in your html so you could just remove the `form_widget(userform.Subscription` section completely.  But that does not explain the error message.

Comment: And you have an extra semi-colon at the end of `->add('Subscription', SubmitType::class);`  which sort of makes me think it is still a syntax issue relating to your roles.

Comment: Ok, I added ->add() and between brackets a new builder with ->get('roles') and ->addModelTransformer inside. It looks okay. :)